# stretched button in the gridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

everyone, I have some problem with Java I created panel with five rows and one column, also I added button to the one of the rows, finally I added this panel to the frame, and I received button which is stretched to full frame, can I reduce the size of the button, I used

```
myButton.setSize(10,10);
```

but it doesn't seem to work, also I use

```
frame.pack();
```

may it be the problem, thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the whole gui creation code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should refrain from setting the size yourself. You should select a proper `LayoutManager` that does the job for you.

(Unless you explicitly do `setLayout(null)` the sizes you set will be discarded and the current layout manager will assign new sizes to the components.)

You say that you're using a `GridLayout`. This layout is fairly "unflexible", and if you want the benefits of `GridLayout` but more flexibility, you could give [`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) a try.

If you don't find a layout manager that suites your needs, don't be afraid of writing your own. (It's five relatively easy methods to implement.)

If you post a screen-shot of your current application, and an explanation on how you want it to look, we'll be able to help you further.

Some useful links

- [Trail: Using Layout Manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
- [Create a Custom Swing/AWT Layout Manager in Java](http://taubler.com/articles/article_Create_a_Custom_Swing_AWT_Layout_Manager_in_Java?id=3)

Answer (score 1):

When aloobe seems to have a more general solution for you. I'd say the immediate solution would be to add the button to a JPanel, set the Layoutmanager a layout like GridLayout, or another LayoutManager, if you find another suits you better.

And add this panel to your original panel, in place of the button.

Comment: My term for that is a 'nested layout'.  I could not imagine creating a workable GUI using any one layout (not even GrievousBodilyLayout, oh excuse me - GridBagLayout).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using layout managers (like `GridLayout`) then calls to `setSize()` generally don't work, because the layout manager ultimately decides how to size and place each component in a container.

What you can do is call `setPreferredSize()`, `setMaximumSize()` and/or `setMinimumSize()`.  Depending on the layout manager in use one or more of these requests (because that's really what they are) will be honoured.  When you call `frame.pack()` it will try to size everything in the container (and subcontainers) to their preferred sizes.

So, in your case, calling `myButton.setPreferredSize (10, 10);` will probably work.  However, it will still be resized if the container changes size.  If you don't want that, there are other solutions I can post.